# How to integrate custom context menus in Mithril

Tags: mithril.js

I'm trying to add custom contextmenus to some of the elements in a page and did 
it like this in a view which contains a table. The contextmenu is attached to
the table header with the name "S":

```js
list.view = function(ctrl, args) {

var contextMenuSelection =      
    m("div", {
    id : "context-menu-bkg-01",
    class : ctrl.isContextMenuVisible() === ctrl.contextMenuId ? "context-menu" : "hide",
    style : ctrl.contextMenuPosition(),
}, [ m("#select.menu-item.allow-hover", {
    onclick : function(e) {
        args.model.callMenu({
            cmdName : this.id
        })
    }
}, "Select all"), m("#deselect.menu-item.allow-hover", {
    onclick : function(e) {
        args.model.callMenu({
            cmdName : this.id
        })
    }
}, "Deselect all"), m("#invertSel.menu-item.allow-hover", {
    onclick : function(e) {
        args.model.callMenu({
            cmdName : this.id
        })
    }
}, "Invert selection") ]);

var table = m("table", [
    m("tr", [ m("th", {
        id : ctrl.contextMenuId,
        config : ctrl.configContextMenu(),
        oncontextmenu : function(e) {
            console.log("2021 contextMenuShow")
            e.preventDefault()
            var coords = utils.getCoords(e)
            var pos = {}
            pos.left = coords[0] + "px"
            pos.top = coords[1] + "px"
            ctrl.contextMenuPosition(pos)
            var id = e.currentTarget.id
            ctrl.isContextMenuVisible(id)
        }
        }, "S"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=pName]", "Name"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=pSize]", "Size"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=pPath]", "Path"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=pMedia]", "Media") ]),
        ctrl.items().map(
           function(item, idx) {
              return m("tr", ctrl.initRow(item, idx), {
              key : item.guid
              }, [ m("input[type=checkbox]", {
                id : item.guid,
                checked : ctrl.isSelected(item.guid)
                }),
                                    m("td", item.pName),
                m("td",  utils.numberWithDots(item.pSize)),
                m("td", item.pPath), m("td", item.pMedia) ])
            }) ])

return m("div", [contextMenuSelection, table])              
}
```

To get the contextmenu closed after the escape key is hit or the user clicks 
somewhere in the page with the mouse, this function is attached to the 
element via the config attribute:

```js
ctrl.configContextMenu = function() { 
    return function(element, isInitialized, context) {
        console.log("1220 isInitialized=" + isInitialized)
        if(!isInitialized) {
           console.log("1225")
           document.addEventListener('click', function() {
              m.startComputation()
              ctrl.contextMenuVisibility(0)
              m.endComputation()
           }, false);
               document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
              console.log("1235")
              m.startComputation()
                          ctrl.contextMenuVisibility(0)
              m.endComputation()
           }, false)
        }
    };  
};
```

The behavior is unpredictable:
If the table is empty, the custom contextmenu shows up and is hidden as expected.
If the table is populated, the default contextmenu is shown instead.

Using a debugger and some breakpoints didn't get me some information what is 
happening except that sometimes running the debugger step by step brought up the
custom contextmenu. So I assume it has something to do with a race condition 
between the eventListener and Mithrils draw system.

Has anybody experience with custom contextmenus and could provide me some
examples?

Thanks a lot,
Stefan

**EDIT:**
As to Barneys comment regarding m.startComputation() I changed the code to the following:

```js
var table = m("table", ctrl.sorts(ctrl.items()), [
m("tr", [ m("th", {
    oncontextmenu : ctrl.onContextMenu(ctrl.contextMenuId, "context-menu context-menu-bkg", "hide" )
}, "S"), m("th[data-sort-by=pName]", "Name"),
m("th[data-sort-by=pSize]", "Size"), 
m("th[data-sort-by=pPath]", "Path"), 
m("th[data-sort-by=pMedia]", "Media") ]), 
ctrl.items().map(function(item, idx) {
    return m("tr", ctrl.initRow(item, idx), {
        key : item.guid
    }, [ m("input[type=checkbox]", {
        id : item.guid,
        checked : ctrl.isSelected(item.guid),
        onclick : function(e) {
            console.log("1000")
            ctrl.setSelected(this.id);
        }
    }), m("td", item.pName), m("td", utils.numberWithDots(item.pSize)), 
    m("td", item.pPath), m("td", item.pMedia) ])
}) ])
```

And the implementing function onContextMenu:

```js
// open a context menu
// @elementId   the id of the element which resembles the context menu.
//              Usually this is a div.
// @classShow   the name of the css class for showing the menu
// @classHide   the name of the css class for hiding the menu
vmc.onContextMenu = function(elementId, classShow, classHide) {
    var callback = function(e) {
        console.log("3010" + this)
        var contextmenudiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
        contextmenudiv.className = classHide;
        document.removeEventListener("click", callback, false);
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", callback, false);
    }
    return function(e) {
        console.log("3000" + this)
        var contextmenudiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
        // Prevent the browser from opening the default context menu
        e.preventDefault();
        var coords = utils.getCoords(e);
        contextmenudiv.style.left = coords[0] + "px";
        contextmenudiv.style.top = coords[1] + "px";
        // Display it
        contextmenudiv.className = classShow;
        // When you click somewhere else, hide it
        document.addEventListener("click", callback, false);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", callback, false);
    }
};
```

Now this works without problems. 
Barney, if you could be so kind to confirm this as a viable way, I'll post it as answer.

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Could you try and reduce the code to a minimum test case? There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code, although `startComputation` is being used in an odd way – the purpose of that code is to block and resume redraws during asynchronous operations, but you're using it synchronously – may as well just call `m.redraw`, or just bind the events as `onclick` and `onkeydown` alongside `oncontextmenu` (Mithril automatically redraws after inline event handlers execute)

Comment: FWIW I couldn't get any weird behaviour out of `oncontextmenu` in this simple [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jezaxi/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it leads to a example how to load modules.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how that happened :/ – I can't find the example I coded up. Nice solution though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution:

```js
var table = m("table", ctrl.sorts(ctrl.items()), [
    m("tr", [ m("th", {
        oncontextmenu : ctrl.onContextMenu(ctrl.contextMenuId, "context-menu  context-menu-bkg", "hide" )
    }, "S"), m("th[data-sort-by=pName]", "Name"),
    m("th[data-sort-by=pSize]", "Size"), 
    m("th[data-sort-by=pPath]", "Path"), 
    m("th[data-sort-by=pMedia]", "Media") ]), 
    ctrl.items().map(function(item, idx) {
        return m("tr", ctrl.initRow(item, idx), {
            key : item.guid
    }, [ m("input[type=checkbox]", {
            id : item.guid,
            checked : ctrl.isSelected(item.guid),
            onclick : function(e) {
                console.log("1000")
            ctrl.setSelected(this.id);
        }
    }), m("td", item.pName), m("td", utils.numberWithDots(item.pSize)), 
    m("td", item.pPath), m("td", item.pMedia) ])
}) ])
```

And the implementing function onContextMenu:

```js
// open a context menu
// @elementId   the id of the element which resembles the context menu.
//              Usually this is a div.
// @classShow   the name of the css class for showing the menu
// @classHide   the name of the css class for hiding the menu
vmc.onContextMenu = function(elementId, classShow, classHide) {
    var callback = function(e) {
        console.log("3010" + this)
        var contextmenudiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
        contextmenudiv.className = classHide;
        document.removeEventListener("click", callback, false);
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", callback, false);
    }
    return function(e) {
        console.log("3000" + this)
        var contextmenudiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
        // Prevent the browser from opening the default context menu
        e.preventDefault();
        var coords = utils.getCoords(e);
        contextmenudiv.style.left = coords[0] + "px";
        contextmenudiv.style.top = coords[1] + "px";
        // Display it
        contextmenudiv.className = classShow;
        // When you click somewhere else, hide it
        document.addEventListener("click", callback, false);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", callback, false);
    }
};
```

Now the context menu is outside of mithrils render cycle and there are no race conditions anymore. Also the click event for hiding the menu is attached to the document and does not get into conflict with a click handler attached by mithril.

Tested with Firefox 38.01